# How to merge MySQL backup files (*.sql)

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, mysqldump, mysql-workbench

We have several `MySQL` backup files of a database in `*.SQL` format and we want to restore the database by using these files. However, as the sql files contains `"DROP TABLE"` definitions, running one script cause to remove the data created by the previous script. In addition to these sql files, we have also some other backup folders containing `*.FRM` and `*.MYD` files. In all of two cases I think these backups are `Differential` or `Incremental` and we have to merge/combine all of them. If so,  how can we combine them without losing data? As I have no experience on `MySQL`, could you explain a way by using `MySQL Workbench` if it is possible? Thanks in advance.